# What web control library to use for easy form creation with many different types of input fields?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, user-controls

I'm about to create a web application that requires a lot of different web forms where the user needs to be able to input a lot of different types of information. What I mean is that one of those forms may require some text input fields, some integer input fields, some decimal input fields, some date input fields, some datetime input fields, etc.

I would like to have a, maybe JavaScript-based, control library that I can simple provide with some text labels, input types and default values. The control library would then somehow render the form in HTML without me having to create an HTML table, select the appropriate standard web controls and all that.

I have used [dhtmlxGrid](http://www.dhtmlx.com/) to create quite a lot of tables and that works well for me. What I need now is something that can help me in a similar way when creating something like card forms.

I have also found [ActiveWidgets](http://www.activewidgets.com/), but it looks like it will require a lot of work on my behalf. I'm not only looking for individual web controls, but rather something like a library that can help me with the overall card.

I'm guessing many of you have had this problem before. Looking forward to hearing what solutions you have found to be the best. BTW: I'm working in VisualStudio with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be tempted to look at Ext JS for this.

[Ext JS](http://extjs.com/products/extjs/)

Answer (score 1):

have you had a look at [InputEx](http://javascript.neyric.com/inputex/)

Answer (score 1):

I know it doesn't answer the question, but I have always written my own, or rather written it once and tweaked it for other apps.  When I store the questions in the DB I store what input type it is, then on the form I dynamically create the appropriate control depending on which input type the question needs and add that control to a dynamically created table cell as I go.

If you choose to do that just remember when processing the form that the controls don't exist on postback, you need to recreate them.

It is not too bad to write it, if you have the time. My current form module is running a few dozen forms from the one module.